# the type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception for Windows XP

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, windows-xp-sp3

My WPF application works fine on Windows 7, but throws the above error when running on Windows XP.
I am using ENtity Framework 6.1.1

App.xaml is

```
<Application.Resources>
    <main:MainConverter x:Key="MainVerter"/>
    <Style x:Key="DetailHead1Style" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkSlateGray"/>
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.8"/>
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="6,2,6,2"/>
    </Style>
    <Style  x:Key="DetailsOuterGridStyle" TargetType="Grid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

The inner exception is

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for entityFramework: Request failed. 
(Q:\devnet10\SBD.CartBrowser\SBD.CartBrowser\bin\Debug\SBD.FlightControl.exe.Config line 23) ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.PerformSecurityCheck(Object obj, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal method, RuntimeType parent, UInt32 invocationFlags)
       at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.PerformSecurityCheck(Object obj, IRuntimeMethodInfo method, RuntimeType parent, UInt32 invocationFlags)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
       at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke(Object[] parameters)
       at System.Configuration.TypeUtil.InvokeCtorWithReflectionPermission(ConstructorInfo ctor)
       at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.CreateSectionImpl(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader)
       at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.CreateSectionWithRestrictedPermissions(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader)
       at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.CreateSection(Boolean inputIsTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader)
       at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.CallCreateSection(Boolean inputIsTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentConfig, ConfigXmlReader reader, String filename, Int32 line)
```

The app.config contains the correct connection string.  Could it be interpreted differently on XP?

[Update]
The code fails when initialising the connection.

```
 var connect = new CartConnect(constr);
```

[Update]

app.config is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CartConnect_HAPPY4" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Edm.CartModel.csdl|res://*/Edm.CartModel.ssdl|res://*/Edm.CartModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Database=mydatabase;Server=Server15\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=False;User=mylogin;Password=mypassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

   <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
   </startup>

</configuration>
```

I set up my connection string using

```
private CartConnect MakeConnect()
{
    string key = string.Format("CartConnect_{0}", Environment.MachineName.ToUpperInvariant());
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[key].ConnectionString;
    var connect = new CartConnect(constr); // fails here

    connect.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    connect.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    return connect;
}
```

I looked at other questions on "An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for entityFramework"

I tried removing and re-adding Entity Framework using NuGet

[Update]

Thank you ErikEJ. Copying the files locally works.   I wonder if there is a way to get it working on the network?

Reminds me of my problem [in this question about regasm](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=wm#label/jtKnowledgebase/143a335874d62245)

Comment: Please post app.xaml file.

Comment: @PiyushParashar  I have updated the question with app.xaml

Comment: Is there any inner exception? Can you debug app.g.cs file?

Comment: I don't have visual studio installed on the XP machine.  I am just trying to figure out how to write an InputBox to cut and paste the stack trace.

Comment: Check the event viewer on XP machine. You write some tracing code to log the errors to a txt file on that machine.

Comment: @PiyushParashar I was able to the stack trace ( hobbling through learning WPF ) I will need to investigate how to log the errors.

Comment: You need to catch the exception and log the innerexception  The outer exception doesn't provide any useful information.

Comment: The exception talks about SBD.FlightControl.exe.Config line 23 - so what does *that* file look like?

Comment: @JonSkeet  I updated the question with app.config which releases as SBD.flightControl.exe for the XP Machine

Comment: Is th Q: drive local? If not, try to run the app from a local drive

Comment: @ErikEJ Thats it! it works if I copy it locally.

Comment: @ErikEJ Would you like to write up the answer? I am thinking that getting the XP machines to work across the network is a different question.

Comment: trying out the hotfix https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2580188?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: I wound up deciding not to branch out to the hotfix, and just run the app locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the Q: drive local? If not, try to run the app from a local drive - the error message indicates that there is a security issue preventing you to run from a network folder.